# Find @HTML.EditorFor(model => model.Username) controler in Controller.cs file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have used HTMLEditor code as below.

I want to clear only one HTMLEditor from a click.  How can I find a particular HTML Editor control in controller.cs file?

```
@model Blog.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register New User";
}
@using Microsoft.Web.Mvc;
@using MVC3MultiSubmitButtonExtension;
<h2>
    Register New User</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fill User Details</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
        </div>
        <p>
            @*  <input type="submit" value="Create" />*@ @*@Html.MultiSubmitButton(Url.Action("Create"), "btnCreate", "Create")*@
            @*  @Html.MultiSubmitButton(Url.Action("Cancel"), "btnCancel", "Cancel", new { @class = "cancel" })*@
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="submit" id="btnReset" name="btnReset"  value="Reset"
                class="cancel" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Click here to go Login Page", "Index")
</div>
```

I want to set string.empty only for EmailAddress HTML Editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the complete form on click of a button you can set the type of button as `type="reset"`.

```
<input type="reset" id="btnReset" name="btnReset"  value="Reset" />
```

If you want to clear a particular field like `EmailAddress` on click of the button then you have to listen to the click event. For that first you have to set a unique id for that button.

```
<input id="clearEmailAddress" type="button" value="Clear Email Address" />

<script type="text/javascript>

$("#clearEmailAddress").click(function(){
     $(this).closest('form').find("input[name='EmailAddress']").val("");
});

</script>
```